# Optimize or simplify MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have Access query which really takes time to execute. Right now, I had to go through to at least four queries to get the result I want which is Top 4 percentage by group. Here are the queries.

1. Query1 - Add calculated field which is column3.
2. Query2 - Add cumulative field for column3.
3. Query3 - Add calculated fields in which I used column3 for calculation. calcfield1, calcfield2, calcfield3 combined them in one column (NewColumn) using UNION query. Sum the NewColumn and grouped them by GroupID.
4. Query4 - Selects the Top 4 values in NewColumn by GroupID.

Sample Output (Top 4 values of NewColumn by GroupID):

```
Group1 1.45
Group1 1.00
Group1 0.45
Group1 0.20
Group2 8.20
Group2 4.48
Group2 3.44
Group2 2.00
```

When I run Query4, it takes a while to execute (at least 10 mins.). The queries has to return all record because of the cumulative percentage calculation.

I tried HAVING clause in Query3 so that rows in Query4 would be minimized when I select the Top 4 but I couldn't get it worked. I also tried getting the Top 4 in Query2 so that succeeding query has less rows to work with but the query takes more time that I have to break the execution of query.

I'd like to simplify or at least optimize the query.

Table Structure:

```
 Table1:
 ID - Autonumber
 GroupID
 Tip1
 Tip2
 Tip3
 Tip4

Sample data Table1:
GroupID    Tip1      Tip2        Tip3      Tip4
171        1          5           4          8
172        2          7           5          3
173        8          16          10          

Table2:
ID - Autonumber
GroupID
Result1
Result2
Result3

Sample data Table2:
GroupID    Result1  Result2     Result3
171        1          5           4    
172        12         7           5    
173        8          6           3
```

Table1 and Table2 are joined using GroupID

Comment: can you show your table structure and some sample input data

Comment: Yes, Query3 must have been the bottleneck because of the UNION of three fields into one. If I can get the Top 4 by group in Query3, I can eliminate Query4. But I don't know how to do that since I have to use HAVING clause with Select Top 4 subquery.

Comment: Update: Only Query4 is very slow. Other queries return records in reasonable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation once where I had to rank data through a complicated self-join.  It was very slow until I first dumped the data into a temp table and then ran update queries on it. Still slow, but not nearly as bad.

Perhaps you could use a staging table instead of a series of joined queries? Then #1,#2, and #3 could be update queries that act on that staging table.

Comment: I actually used staging table for #3. Haven't tried for #1 and #2. Will give it a try.

Comment: By the way, how do I update changes and insert new record on staging table? I mean, how do I catch changes on real table so that changes reflects on staging table?

Comment: It's not hard.  Your question basically translates to "how do i make an update query in Access?" so try Googling that. For example, when you create your staging table (perhaps with a make-table query), include a blank field for 'Column3' and then have an update query populate it.

Comment: I created table similar with query which I intend to update using Update query. Do you think make-table query is necessary? Also, I know how to make Update query. I'm just wondering where's the better place to catch changes so that I can run the Update query, in the Form or in Data Macro.

Comment: I used staging tables with all of my queries. I didn't catch changes so I didn't use UPDATE. I just use DELETE * followed by INSERT. You were right, execution improves. Thanks PowerUser!